# How do we call this shape?

Tags: geometry

I have this 3D shape, and I don't know what it is called. it has 4 surfaces and 4 curved surfaces on the sides, and a surface in the middle on the top and bottom. All surfaces are joined with convex fillets.

[image: Geometrical shape]

Comment: The gem industry might have a name for it??

Comment: I would say it is the dilated of a cuboid (dilated in the sense of "Minkowski sum" of a cuboid and a sphere).